# XSLT: use a variable from a template and apply it to another template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm facing an XSLT problem that may seem obvious but remains challenging for me.
I need to generate a unique ID that must be applied to elements available from different templates.
If the ID is correctly generated and applied in one template, I cannot apply it from one template to another because it is out of scope.

Here is the code I've written so far. Any pointer would be highly appreciated :)

```xml
    <xsl:template match="uicontrol">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()"/>
                    <div class="ft-expanding-block" id="{$id}"/>
   </xsl:template>
    
   
    <xsl:template match="codeblock">     
        <h1><span class="ft-expanding-block-link"  data-target-id="{$id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span></h1>
    </xsl:template>
```

XML example

```xml
<uicontrol>Show example</uicontrol>.
<codeblock>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
{
  "id":"a7d67610-ceb5-4350-ba5a-746472c4f1f7",
  "schemas": [
    "urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0",
    "urn:scim:schemas:com_pingone:1.0" 
  ],
</codeblock>
<p class="- topic/p">The following code block should be expanded on page load with the label <uicontrol>Hide example</uicontrol>.</p>
<codeblock>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
{
</codeblock>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context.

Comment: `generate-id()` will produce the same value for the same node within the same transform. So, rather than trying to reference the variable, just call `generate-id()` and pass in the element that you want the ID for.

Comment: What is `$content`? And why can't you navigate from your template matching `codeblock` to use e.g. `preceding-sibling::uicontrol[1]/generate-id()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a global variable called `content`, and another variable named `id` which depends only on the value of `content` but which is local to one template. If you want to widen the scope of that `id` variable you can just make it a global variable, like the `content` variable. Just move it up out of the `template` which contains it, so that it's a child of the `stylesheet` element.

Comment: I can't use the variable as global  because value of variable is dependent on current node under evaluation.

Comment: Before you edited it, the variable depended only on the global variable `$content`, but I see now you've edited it so that it depends on the current node. So to compute the same id, your second template (that matches `codeblock`) needs to be able to identify the same `uicontrol`. How is the second template to know what is the "current node" which the first template has matched? The first template doesn't call `apply-templates` and hence never invokes the second, so there _is_ no "current node". You need to post a minimal reproducible example, as Michael said in his comment on your question.